# how to know which test is running a particular piece of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, code-coverage

I'm running `bundle exec rake test` to get the coverage with simplecov but once I got the results, the lines that are not covered I want to know which test is actually testing that file.

so for example i have a file named `foo.rb` which is not entering into an else statement. After i ran `bundle exec rake test` it tells me that the `foo.rb` file has, only 99% coverage. Because the else is never run.

Since i have a very large project, with a lot of `_tes.rb` files. I want to know, which test file is running the `foo.rb` file so that i can add a test for the else case.

Is there any way I can know which test is running a portion of that file, maybe with a `pry` or some other gem?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you please clarify with an example?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the original question for better reading

Comment: Simplecov (https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) is one that I've seen used in many projects and it worked just fine.

Comment: SimpleCov does not appear to store this information. If it did, I don't know that it would be useful. Coverage only tells you which code was definitely not tested. It does not tell you what was tested. Looking at what test called what code, you'll get a lot of false positives; tests which incidentally call code but don't check its results. Instead, organize your unit tests to match your code structure. Then you know definitively where the unit tests are. If foo.rb has a piece of code which is never called, then foo.rb needs, at minimum, a unit test in foo_spec.rb.

Comment: i want to know which test is running, in order to add the missing one into the same file. I know tha if the code structure was perfect i wouldn't be asking this. But i have inherit this code, and i need to know which test is running at some point during `rake task`, is there any way? i can add prys and all but how do i get the name of the test that is running?

Comment: Are you able to run a `grep` against the test directory looking for the method or class name to narrow things down?

Comment: Yes i can do a grep, or use fzf or silver searcher. But that is not so quickly i still have to go a test on a bunch of files to see which one is actually running the line i am interested cause ruby includes the whole module o class name an from there they just have a single call as interactors do, an execute a bunch of stuff, which are the ones i am interested in. So this is actually what i have been doing, i need a better approach something that can tell me the test that is running when i put a pry inside some cascade of functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer was very simple. Just put a line of code in the file you are trying to test, let's say it is a controller. Well, in this case, you may put a `context.fail!` or maybe `raise "some error"` and with that, you can run all your tests and see which of all your tests fail. With that, you can at least get a clear log into the console about the test fail that is making a test into the file you are trying to add tests for.

I hope it helps for anyone looking for something like this. And thanks for all your comments.